# Proving an image is diffeomorphic to the Torus

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

If I have,

\begin{align} 
f(u,v) &= (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v))\\
&=(( \sqrt{2} + \cos(u)) \cos(v) , (\sqrt{2} + \cos(u)) \sin(v) , \sin(u)).
\end{align}

where $(u,v) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

I showed that the image set $f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is a submanifold by observing that it is an open set of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Now I want to show that $f(\mathbb{R^2})$ is diffeomorphic to $T^2$

I thought about showing that the function $g(f(\mathbb{R^2}))$ is differentiable by using the chain rule, but to prove that the inverse is differentiable is too much work I think, and I also know bijectivity won't work here, I don't know what should be the 'obvious' way to start this off, any hints?

Comment: $f(\mathbb R^2)$ is not an open set in $\mathbb R^3$.... And what is $g$?

Comment: The diffeomorphism I'm trying to construct from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $T^2$

Comment: There is no diffeomorphism between them: $\mathbb R^2$ is non-compact while $T^2$ is compact.

Comment: That is correct, I got very confused, I meant from $f(\mathbb{R^2})$ to $T^2$

Comment: What is your definition of $T^2$?

Comment: $T^2 = \mathbb{R^2} / \mathbb{Z^2}$